# Overload Conflict in SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have the following code to compute the Hofstadter H Sequence, but I am getting an overload conflict error message. I am fairly new to SML therefore i am sure what the error is referring to.

```
(* Hofstadter H-Sequence *)
fun H(0) = [0]
| H(n) = if  n = 0 then [0] else x :: (n - H(H(H(n - 1))));
```

My goal is to insert the value of each iteration into a list and display it.
Ex: H 10; -->[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write a function with the type `int -> int list`.

(It's a good idea to think about the types while writing, even though SML will infer them. A good type system is like autofocus for the mind.)

You can't subtract the result of this function from a number (`n - H(...)`) since it is a list, nor can you pass a list to to this function – `H(H(n - 1))` – since it wants a number.
(And where did the first element, `x`, come from?)

Start simple, with a function that's just the definition of `H(n)`:

```
fun H 0 = 0
  | H n = n - H(H(H(n-1)))
```

Test:

```
- H 0;
val it = 0 : int
- H 1;
val it = 1 : int
- H 2;
val it = 1 : int
- H 4;
val it = 3 : int
```

Then use that to build a list incrementally.
This variant uses a locally defined helper function that uses the current index and a counter:

```
fun H_seq n = let fun H_seq' m e =
                      if m < e
                      then (H m) :: (H_seq' (m+1) e)
                      else []
              in
                  H_seq' 0 n
              end;
```

Example:

```
- H_seq 10;
val it = [0,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6] : int list
```

This is pretty inefficient, but fixing that is part of the more advanced course...